# git checkout branch and local repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

I have a query about version of file I see in locally. Let's say I have cloned one git repository. So, particular file.txt is corresponding to version '6'

```
1--2--3--4--5--6        --> master
   |--A--B--C--D--E--F  --> BRANCH1
         |--X--Y        --> BRANCH2
```

If I switch to BRANCH1, and do 'git pull' file.txt will correspond to version 'F'?

If I then switch to BRANCH2, and do 'git pull' file.txt will correspond to version 'Y'?

If I again switch back to 'master', will I see version '6'?

Please let me know.

Comment: `If I` When you did, did it? Some [background reading](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics) would be a good idea, instead of asking questions about things you could simply try for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This is because your file.txt in remote github has different versions, for master it’s version 6, for BRANCH1 it’s version F, for BRANCH2 it’s version Y.

So when you just switch to different branches and execute `git pull`, so git will pull the related versions for different branches.

e.g. when you switch to master, and use `git pull`, git will pull the file.txt's version 6 for master from github.

Comment: The question reads like "git pull" is the action that updates the files which is not the case. This answer propagates that misunderstanding by again suggesting that git pull is the action which actually updates files, instead of switching branches. Related and more importantly: you haven't answered the question asked (however bad it was).

Comment: git pull is update current local branch with remote one. Because all remote branches have file.txt (or we call it file.txt has different version).  Isn’t that the point?

Comment: `git pull` is `git fetch` + either `git merge` or `git rebase`. As I mentioned just checking out a commit/branch is the step which actually updates files, unless the remote has been updated since the last pull/fetch as the last step also checks out the new state. The question is confusing; but this answer is also - it reads like an svn understanding of git.

Comment: Yes, I know what’s `git pull` means. But it’s impossible for us to tell anyone when and where to use `git pull`. And it’s doesn’t matter to use git pull even the local branch is up-to-date. The reason for file.txt changed the version is cause by checkout to different branches, do you agree with me? BTW, I’m more familiar with git than svn.